Mockito Not returning the mock response
Method In Test:

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Component
public class Adapter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(Adapter.class);

  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Adapter(RestTemplate restTemplate){
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

public void getPost(String titleId,List<Normalize> normalize) {
    try{
        PostingTitle postingTitle = null;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.set("Accept", "*/*");
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(CommonUtils.createPostingBody(titleId).toString(), headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(postPostURL, request, String.class);
}

Unit Test:

import org.mockito.*;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AdapterTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private Adapter lcAdap;

    @Mock
    private ResponseEntity response;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<HttpEntity> entityCaptor;


@Test
public void testGetExtract_Success() throws Exception {
    // Setup
    String description = "Some description";
    List<Normalized> normalizedDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
    String jsonResponse = "{ \"data\": "test" }";

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
 
    map.put("text", finalDescription);
   
    HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);


    ResponseEntity<String> mockResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(jsonResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

    // Mock the behavior of RestTemplate's postForEntity
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<Map>>any(),ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any()))
            .thenReturn(mockResponse);
    // Action
    lc.getPost(description, normalizedDetailsList);
}

}

This above unit test is not returning response. It's returning null for the mock response. Can someone help with this proper mock response.., for this method ?
I would like to extract the mock response which can further works as expected to parse the data and assert the data.

Where is restTemplate defined, and are you sure the restTemplate in the method getPost is the same instance as in the unit test?

@k314159 I update the classes with its implementations and import statements. I'm using same restTemplate.

try restTemplate.postForEntity(any(), any(), any()), if will work, then your some of arguments of restTemplate.postForEntity is null and e.g. anyString is not matched with null values

@GeorgiiLvov I tried it like this.,    Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(),any(),any()))                 .thenReturn(mockResponse); But its showing some compilation issue for mockResponse. with cannot resolve method thenReturn(mockresponse).

Then look at arguments, if someone is null during test execution, e.g. postPostURL then change it to ArgumentMatchers.isNull()

I cannot reproduce. I copied your code, fixed the compilation errors (and added the truncated bits). Test passes, and response inside the function prints as <200 OK OK,{ "data": "test" },[]>.

Your matchers don't match. You are mocking for HttpEntity<Map> while you are submitting a HttpEntity<String>. No match, so default behavior which will be null. Your matchers seem also overly complicated.

@M.Deinum well spotted, but can this really be the issue? I thought generic type erasure would make it undetectable at runtime whether you pass ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<Map>>any() or ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<String>>any().

Some information is still available through reflection/introspection and I suspect that is what Mockito is using. Spring uses the same when doing injection with generic types.

I'm with k314159 here: generics are erased and not available at runtime (they are only available on method declarations and subclasses, not on method invocations). Also see my previous comment: the code works and the stubbed value is returned.
